# Convert YouTube DASH audio (youtube-dl) to m4a (AAC DL)

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, youtube, audio-conversion, youtube-dl

I am unable to listen to m4a DASH audio I download from YouTube via youtube-dl on Winamp. Is there an option in youtube-dl to remove the DASH audio part of m4a file and download/save it as an m4a (AAC LC) without loss of quality? So far, I am using  `ffmpeg -i input.m4a -vn -acodec copy output.m4a` to convert each file so it plays properly in Winamp.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> youtube-dl 2015.01.23.4 and newer will automatically correct the
>   header of the m4a file if ffmpeg is present on the system.

<sup>Source: [youtube-dl
: Youtube m4a files downloaded with --extract-audio can't play in some players](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/3681)</sup>
All you have to do is to add the path to the directory containing the ffmpeg binary to your [system path variable](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) (like so in Windows 7):

[image]

Or use the `--ffmpeg-location <path to ffmpeg binary or its containing directory>` command line argument when calling youtube-dl, to allow youtube-dl through ffmpeg to automatically correct this.

Comment: My question was appropriate in Nov 14. youtube-dl author addressed the issue in Jan 15. Glad it is part of youtube-dl now.

Answer (score 7):

No, you need a second conversion step.

The problem is that for YouTube DASH, the MP4 container's `ftyp` has the "major brand" set to `dash` instead of `m4a`. This is the correct approach for DASH streaming, but Winamp is too old to recognize it (and many other programs are).

Now, what would be a reasonable suggestion is to create a feature request for youtube-dl to add post-processing support for ffmpeg to convert the major brand of the MP4 container to something more compatible. But at the moment, such a thing does not exist.

Or, file a bug report for Winamp to include decoding support for `dash` brands. Since it's likely to rely on a third-party decoder plugin, this probably means raising a bug report somewhere else, too.

Comment: Do you think the ffmpeg parameters I am currently using is best for converting it from MPEG DASH m4a to AAC LC m4a?

Comment: Yes. You're not actually converting the audio bitstream itself – you're just changing the metadata. This is a lossless process, so you won't lose audio quality.

Comment: It's not an opinion. The build of Winamp appears to be too old to have implemented the (rather recent) MPEG-4 brands from the MPEG-DASH standard. Other software supports it. And like I said, some other programs may fail.

Answer (score 1):

I took the liberty of using your `ffmpeg` command and this is what I got: `yt "My Youtube File.mp4"`

A file `yt.bat` placed in system32 containing:

```
@echo off
move %1 "_%~n1"
ffmpeg -i "_%~n1" -vn -c:a copy "%~n1.m4a"
del "_%~n1"
```

*renames automatically to `m4a`, which can be changed in the code.

**it needs to be through temp file and then using rm, mv, otherwise the file and filename get corrupted.

Comment: @sunk818 You are absolutely right about the file deletion in case something goes wrong. I guess I could add some kind of a check. ..But then, I run this command right after youtube download, so I can just download it again.

Comment: it works, but change mv to move and rm to del. Also drag-and-drop works too!