# Unable to play mp3 file on some devices?

Tags: audio, vlc-media-player, mp3, codec

I have noticed a certain phenomenon over the last few years... Some mp3 files do not work with certain devices:

Example:
If I download a file file from the internet, I will be able to listen to it using the 'Google Play Music' app on my phone and VLC & Groove Music will also play it but multiple music players just refuse to do so. (I have tried Sony mp3 players, a Philips GoGear, the stereos in my cars and even an old Symbian based phone). They just skip the track after about 2 seconds of silence. I don't get any errors.

I suspect it may be due to codec issues or maybe the files are of a new version of mp3 (?) but I really don't know...

Example File:

http://rahul2001.com/Tobu%20-%20Seven%20[NCS%20Release].mp3

Comment: I just realized that many (but not all) of these files were downloaded using the same Youtube-MP3 converter.

Comment: Looking at the file header for that file, it shows `ftypdash` and `iso6mp41` which implies it's DASH audio, which is not an mp3, which is why certain players won't render the file. Take a look at [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/837067/convert-youtube-dash-audio-youtube-dl-to-m4a-aac-dl) which has more if you're interested in converting it ..